# \AtEndPreamble hook breaks hyperref with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, preamble, hooks

In the past I used `\usepackage{hyperref}` within the `\AtEndPreamble{}` hook, without problems. At least I think so. However, recently the hook breaks the links to my bibliograpy. Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong? I use the hook within a custom class file but load additional packages in the main document file and would like to maintain the loading of hyperref at the end of the preamble.

In the following MWE, everything works fine without the hook, and with the hook the link disappears.

```
\begin{filecontents}{bla.bib}
@article{Orwell,
    author  = "George Orwell and Aldous Huxley and William Shakespeare and Oscar Wilde",
    title   = "1984",
    year    = "1948",
    journal = "Books about big brothers",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bla.bib}

\AtEndPreamble{
    \usepackage{hyperref}
}

\begin{document}

\cite{Orwell}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably have a typo in the last sentence. There seems to be an `out` missing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to manually activate the biblatex support for hyperref in such a situation:

```
\begin{filecontents}{bla.bib}
@article{Orwell,
    author  = "George Orwell and Aldous Huxley and William Shakespeare and Oscar Wilde",
    title   = "1984",
    year    = "1948",
    journal = "Books about big brothers",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,hyperref=manual]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bla.bib}

\AtEndPreamble{
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \BiblatexManualHyperrefOn
}

\begin{document}

\cite{Orwell}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

See also the discussion here https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/585